# How to make an HTML table border in Racket

Tags: racket

I can construct a basic table, but I'm not sure how to make a table border. I have tried multiple variations of code to no avail.

```
 (list 'table                ;this is where I tried border attributes
                 
                     (list 'tr 
                           (list 'th "Key")
                           (list 'th "Value")
                           )
                     (list 'tr
                           (list 'td "A")
                           (list 'td "Blue")
                           )
                     (list 'tr
                           (list 'td "B")
                           (list 'td "Gold")
)
```

I'm not sure of the syntax for border, or the attributes that can be defined. I'm just trying to cram HTML tags into Racket with very little direction. I have tried:

```
'border 1 
(list 'border 1
'border 1 solid black
```

and variations of the above.

Comment: This seems to me to be more of an html question then a racket one. Can you tell us what you are using to convert s-expressions to html? (I'm going to presume its something like x-expressions, but that should be stated explicitly in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

I did some more tinkering and came up with:

```
(list 'table
                     (list
                      (list 'border "1"))
                 
                     (list 'tr 
                           (list 'th "Key")
                           (list 'th "Value")
                           )
                     (list 'tr
                           (list 'td "A")
                           (list 'td "Blue")
                           )
                     (list 'tr
                           (list 'td "B")
                           (list 'td "Gold")
                           )
               )
)
```

Which displays a 1px border around the table/rows/columns.